# How can i json_encode long html?

Tags: php

If I have a large html markup that gets populated with values from the database and gets echoed containig lots of divs that have classes:

```
echo "<div>";
  echo"<div class='className'> {$_results['value']} </div>";
echo"</div>";
. . . 
// large markup incoming
```

How can I save this in a variable so I can send it back as json ? is it possible to do that ?

This is what I am trying to do:

```
$html = "echo "<div>";
      echo"<div class='className'> {$_results['value']} </div>";
    echo"</div>";"

      echo json_encode(array('html'=> $html, 'otherValue' => $_results['otehr']);
```

I just don't know how to save all the html in a variable so I can send it back in an array along with other values that need to be used separately.

Comment: Why would you want to turn it into JSON?

Comment: @trincot I have other values that get need to get encoded so I can use them in a different place, I need to append the markup somewhere, and use the other values for something else

Comment: Just remove `echo` and use concatenation of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `echo` means that you output strings. So, if you don't need to output all strings, then **concatenate** them into one and assign this final string to a variable, e.g.:

```
$html = "<div>" 
    . "<div class='className'>" . $_results['value'] . "</div>"
    . "</div>";

echo json_encode(array('html'=> $html, 'otherValue' => $_results['otehr']));
```

A simple [fiddle](https://3v4l.org/h4bOj).

Comment: Thank you, that works, but, I am using this In a foreach and when I append this in a div every thing looks … broken, do I need to encode the array differently if im using a foreach loop ?

Comment: I __don't know__ what is happening in your `foreach`. Ask a new question or modify this one.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you what I think is a great advice.

Use a template system for this, I will recommend you mustacheJS

It will be a little difficult the first time, but you will gain a better and clear code.